# Stanza.io Could not create WebRTC answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp, ejabberd, stanza.io

Im using ejabberd + stanza.io to make a realtime messaging website,
everything is working perfectly.
now im willing to implement Webrtc audio/video using the jingle protocole.
this is my JS code that i use to connect:

```
var client = XMPP.createClient({
  jid: xmpp_user+'@'+XMPP_DOMAIN,
  password: cu.auth.user_password,
  transport: 'websocket',
  wsURL: "ws://"+xms+":5280/websocket/"
});


client.jingle.config.debug = true;


client.on('session:started', function () {
  client.enableCarbons();
  client.getRoster(function (err, resp) {
    client.updateCaps();
    client.sendPresence({
      caps: client.disco.caps
    });
  });
});

client.connect();
```

the problem is when i call the user from an other app (AstraChat: iOS app that support Jingle) i get this in browser log:

```
Jingle: 67bzrsog243: session-initiate undefined undefined
Jingle: 67bzrsog243: Could not create WebRTC answer undefined undefined
```

this is the xml that astrachat is sending:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en' to='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b@h2745110.stratoserver.net/352555070032013318140962' from='med@h2745110.stratoserver.net/AstraChat-iOS-21820150' type='get' id='3e8kjajc22'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq>
<r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
<a h='1' xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
<a h='2' xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
jingle:created
iq:set:jingle
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en' to='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b@h2745110.stratoserver.net/352555070032013318140962' from='med@h2745110.stratoserver.net/AstraChat-iOS-21820150' type='set' id='3e8kjajc23'><jingle xmlns='urn:xmpp:jingle:1' action='session-initiate' initiator='med@h2745110.stratoserver.net/AstraChat-iOS-21820150' responder='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b@h2745110.stratoserver.net/352555070032013318140962' sid='3e8kjajc24'><content creator='initiator' name='voice'><description xmlns='urn:xmpp:jingle:apps:rtp:1' media='audio'><payload-type id='101' name='speex' clockrate='8000'/></description><transport xmlns='urn:xmpp:jingle:transports:ice-udp:1' pwd='TC5NsD6IEQGXeDO8d5/3OU' ufrag='yA0z'/></content></jingle></iq>
<r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
Jingle: 3e8kjajc24: session-initiate undefined undefined
Could not create WebRTC answer undefined undefined
```

i really have no clue on how to fix that, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you show the xml of the jingle session initiate stanza that astrachat is sending? Its voip stuff might not be compatible with WebRTC.

Comment: @PhilippHancke ive updated my answer to cover the stanza that astrachat is sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the session-initiate from Astra chat is this according to your logs:

`<iq xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b@h2745110.stratoserver.net/352555070032013318140962" from="med@h2745110.stratoserver.net/AstraChat-iOS-21820150" type="set" id="3e8kjajc23">
    <jingle xmlns="urn:xmpp:jingle:1" action="session-initiate" initiator="med@h2745110.stratoserver.net/AstraChat-iOS-21820150" responder="c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b@h2745110.stratoserver.net/352555070032013318140962" sid="3e8kjajc24">
        <content creator="initiator" name="voice">
            <description xmlns="urn:xmpp:jingle:apps:rtp:1" media="audio">
                <payload-type id="101" name="speex" clockrate="8000" />
            </description>
            <transport xmlns="urn:xmpp:jingle:transports:ice-udp:1" pwd="TC5NsD6IEQGXeDO8d5/3OU" ufrag="yA0z" />
        </content>
    </jingle>
</iq>`

which only offers the speex audio codec that WebRTC does not support (opus or G.711 are mandatory). Also there is no encryption which is mandatory in WebRTC.

Comment: are you aware of any jingle client that support opus ? 
by encryption do u mean using SSL ?

Comment: well it turns out that using letsencrypt certificate and an other webrtc instance (on an other computer solved my problem)
thanks 4 ur help